# "compiler message file broken" - I guess a java compiler bug?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-9

Take the code:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread((new I() {})::test);
    }

    interface I {
        private void test() {}
    }
}
```

And try to compile. I receive:

```
A.java:5: error: invalid method reference
        new Thread(((new I() {}))::test);
                   ^
  compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.cant.resolve.args arguments=method, test, , , {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
```

Where `compiler message file broken` seems to be something incomprehensible. Is it a bug or I am missing something?

P.S. Submitted a bug: ID : 9052216

Comment: this is obviously a bug and should be reported if already isn't. it should simple say something along the lines of `private method can not be accessed...` or `method is not visible/present` whatever

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215297/interface-with-private-method-as-functional-interface#48215886

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Admitted as a bug by the Java Development Support:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194997